# Parse JArray inside of JArray using JSON.Net

Tags: arrays, json.net

I am currently trying to get the data out of an array that is inside another array in a json file.  Unfortunately I am not really knowledgeable in LINQ so I am doing it all in C#

Sample of JSON File

```
"Fruits": [
            {
              "type": "banana",
              "FunFact": [
                {
                  "$": "Yellow"
                },
                {
                  "$": "Long"
                },
                {
                  "$": "People love them"
                }
              ]

            }
      ]
```

Currently this is my code.

```
var csfdata = token.Value<JArray>("Fruit");
            //There are 8 of these Fruit Arrays
            var csfcount = csfdata.Count;
            Console.WriteLine("Length of CSFArray is {0}", csfcount.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < csfcount; i++)
            {
            //Work just fine
            Console.WriteLine("Fruit: {0}", token.SelectToken("Fruit[" + i.ToString() +"].type").ToString());

            //Crashes here saying that FunFact is null or empty when I am trying to get a count of how many is in FunFact
            var tfdata = token.Value<JArray>("FunFact");
            var tfcount = tfdata.Count;

            }
```

Any suggestions and unfortunately I can't do LINQ at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, two preliminary problems:

- Your JSON is invalid, it is missing outer curly braces `{` and `}`.  Without the outer braces Json.NET will not parse your JSON.
- The root property in the JSON is named `"Fruits"` but in your code you use the property name `"Fruit"`.  These need to match.

I suspect that both of these problems are typos in the question.

Assuming these preliminary issues are resolved, your problem is that, in the expression `token.Value<JArray>("FunFact")`, you are using the method [`JToken.Value<T>(Object key)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Value__1.htm) to fetch the value of the token `"FunFact"` from the root `token` and then convert it to type `JArray`.  But there is no property `"FunFact"` belonging to the root token.  Instead it belongs to `csfdata[i]`, so you need to do:

```
var tfdata = csfdata[i].Value<JArray>("FunFact");
```

**Update**

*I want to see if it is an array or an object, how can I tell via code?*

In that case don't use the `JToken.Value<T>(Object key)` method, just fetch the value directly using the [item indexer](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Item.htm) then check the type directly:

```
var tfdata = csfdata[i]["FunFact"];
if (tfdata is JArray)
{
    var tfArray = (JArray)tfdata;
    // Process the array
}
else if (tfdata is JObject)
{
    var tfObj = (JObject)tfdata;
    // Process the object
}
```

Or, check the [`Type`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Type.htm) property instead:

```
var tfdata = csfdata[i]["FunFact"];
if (tfdata != null && tfdata.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    var tfArray = (JArray)tfdata;
    // Process the array
}
else if (tfdata != null && tfdata.Type == JTokenType.Object)
{
    var tfObj = (JObject)tfdata;
    // Process the object
}
```

`JToken.Value<T>(Object key)` is useful when you expect the value to be convertible to a certain type and want an exception thrown if not.

Comment: var tfdata = csfdata[i].Value<JArray>("FunFact"); is the correct answer.  Thank you so much!  Apologies for the followup bu if I want to see if it is an array or an object, how can I tell via code.  If I do this:

if (csfdata[i].Value<JArray>("FactorText") is JArray)

I get a invalid cast from JObject to JArray